# height issue with display grid

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website and I ran into an issue with this part of my website. So I'm trying to add a skills section and I used `display: grid`, but the height is not matched with its content. The height is shorter than it should be.
First, I tried to fix it with height: x vh, but I realized it might not be the perfect solution for responsiveness.

I can also share the link to my website if you prefer.

```css
.skills-section {
  background-color: #626262;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.skills-header {
  font-family: 'Martel', serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.skills-container {
  justify-items: center;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100%);
}

.skills-header p,
.fa-html5,
.fa-css3-alt,
.fa-sass,
.fa-js-square,
.fa-dollar-sign,
.fa-react,
.fa-fire,
.fa-node-js,
.fa-git-alt,
.fa-cogs,
.fa-universal-access,
.fa-mobile-alt {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #F99A14;
}

.skills-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.skills-logo p{
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
    <section class="skills-section">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="skills-header">
          <p>Skills</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i>
            <p>HTML</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <p>CSS</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-sass fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Sass</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-js-square fa-3x"></i>
            <p>JavaScript</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign fa-3x"></i>
            <p>jQuery</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x"></i>
            <p>React</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fas fa-fire fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Firebase</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-node-js fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Node js</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fab fa-git-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Git</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Rest APIs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fas fa-universal-access fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Web Accessibility</p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-logo">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Responsive Design</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Which element's height is not matched?

Comment: the whole section --> skills-section

Comment: You've not added the "height" property to your skills-section. Is that the issue?

Comment: I added "height: 60vh" but it doesn't work properly on different resolutions. That's why I deleted it and I thought I should find the best solution.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Ok now I have added height: auto to the code in here. But still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, and found out that why is it happening like this. I have just removed one piece of code, and it worked! Code snippet below:

```css
.skills-section {
  background-color: #626262;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 85%;
}

.skills-header {
  font-family: 'Martel', serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.skills-container {
  justify-items: center;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 95px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2);
}

.skills-header p,
.fa-html5,
.fa-css3-alt,
.fa-sass,
.fa-js-square,
.fa-dollar-sign,
.fa-react,
.fa-fire,
.fa-node-js,
.fa-git-alt,
.fa-cogs,
.fa-universal-access,
.fa-mobile-alt {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #F99A14;
}

.skills-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.skills-logo p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="skills-section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="skills-header">
        <p>Skills</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skills-container">
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i>
          <p>HTML</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i>
          <p>CSS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-sass fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Sass</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-js-square fa-3x"></i>
          <p>JavaScript</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign fa-3x"></i>
          <p>jQuery</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-react fa-3x"></i>
          <p>React</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-fire fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Firebase</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-node-js fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Node js</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fab fa-git-alt fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Git</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Rest APIs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-universal-access fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Web Accessibility</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-3x"></i>
          <p>Responsive Design</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can also add some [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)  queries to change the number of rows and columns as per different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100%);` and it should fit everything.

Or keep it and change that `100%` to almost anything else besides a `%` value if its necessary and it should work.